# Show message empty result after filter data angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am creating a app using angularjs. I have Integrated multiple filters and search result according to filters.but I am unable to show message no result when filter returns no result. Here is my code:

```
 <div dir-paginate="partners in partnersData|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:partners.name|filter:partners.website|filter:partners.location|itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
          <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv"><span   ng-click="makeFavourite(partners)" class="star_rating" ng-class="{'select':partners.select}"></span> <span ng-click="showImage($index)"></span></div>
            <div class="cellDiv" ng-click="showName($index)">{{partners.name}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.website}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.location}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.service}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.connection}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">{{partners.action}}</div>
            <div class="cellDiv lastCell"><span class="icon_pluse" ng-click="openPlus($index)"></span><span class="icon_info" ng-click="openInfo($index)"></span></div>
          <div ng-if="partnersData.length === 0">No Items Found</div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of angular 1.4 you can create an alias for filtered array using `as aliasName` that will be added to current scope. It is important that `as` comes after all filters in the expression

```
<div dir-paginate="partners in partnersData|orderBy:...|...| lastFilter as filteredArray">

</div>

<!-- Outside paginate directive -->
<div ng-if="!filteredArray.length">No results</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if partnersData's length is 0, which will not occur if filtered.
Instead assign the filtered items to a new variable:

```
<div ng-repeat="partners in filtered = (partnersData | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort|filter:partners.name|filter:partners.website|filter:partners.location|itemsPerPage: pageSize)">
</div>
```

then check `filtered.length`